# Guidelines for tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis

I'm interested in working more on tag wikis that have little to no information. I had a few questions:

1. Is there any consensus on whether the tag wiki should begin with a complete sentence or as a continuation of a sentence beginning with the tag name? (example: (coupon-collector) excerpt: refers to a problem in..) or (example: (coupon-collector) excerpt: This is a famous problem...)
2. Should the main tag wiki contain the excerpt as well as additional material, or should it not repeat the excerpt?

Comment: Personally, when I write tag excerpts (the ones that show in the popup), I try to keep the description short and to the point, but still a complete sentence. For the tag wiki proper, you can do an elaboration of what was written in the excerpt. It's probably not too useful to quote the excerpt verbatim in the wiki proper; better to write paragraphs that flow naturally.

Comment: Some (brief) guidelines are given [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/trusted-user).